# What is a word describing being well enough off in your own life that you turn to helping others?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes a situation where a person becomes well enough off in their other needs that they turn to helping others?

I'm thinking specifically about how celebrities turn their focus on charities and communities once they get to a certain status.  I'm looking for a name for that situation, NOT an adjective to describe the person.

**Example:** Leonardo DiCaprio has reached such a place in his career that he can focus on philanthropy without the need to constantly work.  *His hierarchy of needs has been satisfied to a point where he is now searching for fulfillment in helping others.*

The *italicized* area is the word I'm looking for.  I'm looking for the search for helping others when you no longer have to focus on helping yourself.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Philanthropy* or *philanthropism* seems close to what you describe, but not quite the same.

Comment: This is called *giving back [to the community]* or *paying it forward*.

Comment: You'd have to rephrase both sentences, but [self actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization) seems like a phrase to consider.

Comment: J. Siebeneichner has it. Philanthropy describes giving, and usually by someone well off… but giving specifically because you're well enough off makes it very difficult.

"Lady Bountiful" describes a rather rich wife turning to charitable works partly for duty and party for something to do with her empty days

However, "Lady Bountiful" usually includes a sense that she's not being altruistic but wants recognition and she has no male counterpart.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin That's almost perfect.  If not for the boredom/recognition aspect, that would be it.

Comment: Sorry but philanthropy and altruism both describe motive, not riches; else why, for instance, would we have a tale famously entitled The Ragged-Trousered Philanthropist?

Lady Bountiful had the riches and at least half the motive.

I don't think there are closer terms but why could you not use, say, "rich philanthropist"?

Answer (score -1):

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/philanthropist)

*philanthropist*

> a wealthy person who gives money and time to help make life better for other people

Comment: This seems to be a noun describing the person, not a name for that situation.

Answer (score -2):

```
Altruist
```

Synonymous to philanthropist as already answered by @devc2

Attaching screenshot from the WordWeb dictionary app that I've installed on my Windows computer which shows synonyms and names of famous celebrated altruists.[image]

Comment: Unless a definition of 'altruist' from a dictionary including the modifier 'wealthy' is added, I will not accept that the overlap of the synonyms is sufficient, and will feel obliged to downvote.

Comment: This seems to be a noun describing the person, not a name for that situation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Answer edited with proof that contains even list of celebrities as requested in the question

Comment: But this does not make 'wealthy' a requirement for being an altruist. It just shows that _some_ altruists are wealthy. Indeed,  Jesse Marczyk Ph.D., in a [Psychology Today article titled _The Altruism of the Rich and the Poor_](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/pop-psych/201508/the-altruism-the-rich-and-the-poor), writes:  '[C]haritable giving appears to evidence a U-shaped distribution, in which the richest and poorest sections of the population contribut[e] a greater percentage of their income than those in the middle'